# ios store data into MySQL database simple

Tags: php, mysql, ios, insert-into

I want to save certain user information from my iOS app into a MySQL DB. And I want to keep it simple, since there is no need for ultra-high security level and huge amounts of data.

All I want is: Click a button -> connect to DB (in best case directly) and `INSERT TO` the 5 values onto a single table in the DB.

In my case I use localhost and MySQL-DB named `FooDB` and a table named `FooTable` with 5 columns.

Comment: Show what have you tried ?

Comment: Simplest way would be to expose a RESTful webservice which would be independent of the way you store data.

Comment: I don't use any Framework, because I don't have a real idea how i can solve it. I looked through some tutorials but it wasn't a big help. [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) Tutorial not work for me. And my php knowledge is rather superficial.

Comment: You can also look into [Parse](https://www.parse.com/products/data#pricing) which provides a backend for mobile applications.

Comment: @Anupdas i'ts a nice feature, but in my case I have enough resources for my App. I am looking for RESTful webservices via PHP right now. Maybe anyone has a good source?

Comment: The truly Q&D way would be to have MySQL [listen on the external IP](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33018/how-to-bind-to-static-ip-address-in-mysql) and connect using a [SQL framework for iOs](http://demianturner.com/2009/08/mysql-framework-for-iphone/‎). If you need further assistance, leave a comment and I'll post sample code as an answer.

Comment: @hd1 that sounds great! I learn almost entirely with sample codes. There is a bunch of Information wich I need to increase knowledge. P.S. the second link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework such as PhoneGap or Flex? You haven't given us enough info to aid in providing a solution.